# Embed YouTube Video Inside of Zurb Joyride Plugin

Tags: jquery, youtube

I'm using the [Zurb Joyride plugin](http://www.zurb.com/playground/jquery-joyride-feature-tour-plugin) for a website tour and trying to embed a YouTube video inside on of the tour steps.

Embedding the video isn't a problem, but when hitting the "Next" button, I'm trying to get the YouTube video to Pause. Otherwise, it will continue playing in the background even after a user has gone on to the next step.

The Joyride plugin does has a callback method for going to the next step but I cannot figure out how to make the YouTube video pause when the user clicks "Next"

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

(here is a broken example...the tour works, but not sure how to get the video inside and to have it pause when hitting "Next": http://adamrotman.com/demos/test/demo/testing.html)

Answer (score 0):

Joyride provides `postStepCallback` callback which is executed after each step. You can try to it to do Pase Youtube video.